# Rails 4 shallow routes resource form submission not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I've got shallow nested resource routes like below:

```
    resources :venues, shallow: true do
        #Halls
        get "hall/:id/exhibition" => "halls#exhibition", as: :exhibition
        get "hall/:id/visit" => "halls#visit", as: :hall_visit
        get "structure", :to => "venues#venue_structure"
        resources :asset_types, :booths_tags, :tags, :uploaded_files, :events, :chats
        resources :halls do
            resources :webcasts
            resources :booths do
                resources :chats
            end
        end
    end
```

Below is a simple_form that is currently being used.

```
= simple_form_for(hall_booths_path(@booth), :html => { :class => "form-horizontal" }, :wrapper => "horizontal", defaults: { :input_html => { class: "form-control"}, label_html: { class: "col-lg-4" } } ) do |f|
  = f.simple_fields_for @booth do |b|
```

The problem is that `hall_booths_path(@booth)` part is generating `/halls/1/booths/new` instead of `/halls/1/booths`

Is there something wrong here that needs fixing?

my `booths` routes:

```
hall_booths_path     GET     /halls/:hall_id/booths(.:format)    booths#index
                     POST    /halls/:hall_id/booths(.:format)    booths#create
new_hall_booth_path  GET     /halls/:hall_id/booths/new(.:format)    booths#new
edit_booth_path      GET     /booths/:id/edit(.:format)  booths#edit
booth_path           GET     /booths/:id(.:format)   booths#show
                     PATCH   /booths/:id(.:format)   booths#update
                     PUT     /booths/:id(.:format)   booths#update
                     DELETE  /booths/:id(.:format)   booths#destroy
```

Comment: can you post the output of "rake routes" in your app path???

Comment: @beck03076 I just updated my answer with routes

Comment: @beck03076 I tried that but getting same url with different hall id which is `/halls/3/booths/new` I'm still getting `/new` appended

Comment: then why dont you just do this.. simple_form_for("/halls/#{@hall.id}/booths"..

Comment: @beck03076 still coming up with same result...maybe it's because of `simple_fields_for`?

Comment: Come here..http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12577/help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the path in the options hash, not as the first argument:

```
<%= simple_form_for :booth, :url => hall_booths_path(@hall) do |f| %>
    ...
<% end %>
```

Note that the argument to `hall_booths_path` is a `Hall`, not a `Booth`. When you create a child, you need to supply the parent.

Another option is to pass not the URL but the model objects. Assuming `@hall` is an existing `Hall` and `@booth` is a new `Booth`:

```
<%= simple_form_for [@hall, @booth] do %>
    ...
<% end %>
```

I find this approach much simpler.